# Document two python applications with similar structure using sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

The folder structure looks as follows:

```
|- ext
|   | - app.py
|   | - extensions.py (creates db instance)
|   | - models/ (containing sqlalchemy models)
|   | - routes/ (containing endpoint-files)
|- services
|   | - app.py
|   | - extensions.py (creates db instance)
|   | - models/ (containing sqlalchemy models)
|   | - routes/ (containing endpoint-files)
|- docs
|   | [sphinx data]
```

Both flask applications belong to one project, but cannot be merged.
Normally i would just extend the path in the sphinx conf.py like this:

`sys.path.append(os.path.join(up(up(os.path.dirname(__file__))), "server", "services"))`

But when i use this i can only access the methods of either the routes `services` or `ext`.

```
.. automodule:: routes.auth
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
```

If i only append the path one dir higher like this:

`sys.path.append(os.path.join(up(up(os.path.dirname(__file__))), "server"))`

and try to import the module like:

```
.. automodule:: services.routes.auth
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
```

I get the error

```
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'auth' from module 'services.routes'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'extensions'
```

when trying to build the document.

What would be the proper solution for the issue?